# How do you run a bat file and a custom cmd file from vb resources?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run a batch file with a cmd file I have in my resources. I'm not trying to extract them anywhere. I simply want to edit the bat command in the form and run it with the cmd file I have. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to run a `.cmd` or `.bat` file without saving it to disk first. It has to be there for `cmd.exe` to read and interpret. You'll have to save it to disk first and run it from there.

Once you save it, you can run it using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). From the link's VB.Net example:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace MyProcessSample
Class MyProcess

  Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim myProcess As New Process()

      Try                ' Get the path that stores user documents.
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        ' You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe"
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        myProcess.Start()
        ' This code assumes the process you are starting will terminate itself. 
        ' Given that is is started without a window so you cannot terminate it 
        ' on the desktop, it must terminate itself or you can do it 
        ' programmatically from this application using the Kill method.
      Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine((e.Message))
      End Try
    End Sub 'Main
  End Class
End Namespace
```